# How to synchronize an event receiver and a SP worflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, event-receivers

On a list item, an event receiver(async-onItemUpdated) sets the item's permissions. I want to create a SPD workflow that sets some values to fields. Can these work together?

Thank you

Comment: Why you require to create workflow? you can set value using event receiver.

Comment: I like my code to do certain things - i.e. event receiver=permissions. But as a last resort, it would do that.

Comment: You can set item permission from workflow